# set selected text from auto suggestions in the searchview which is in the form of string

Tags: java, android, json, api, parsing

I am using a SearchView and I;m getting auto suggestion from the API response while typing the text in the search field.

When I am selecting the item from auto suggestions I am getting error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.database.MatrixCursor cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

can u please help me with this? Thank you

Code is :

```
  final String[] columnNames = {"_id","name"};
                        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
                        String[] temp = new String[2];
                        int i=0;
                        for(String item : list){
                            temp[0] = Integer.toString(i++);
                            temp[1] = item;
                            cursor.addRow(temp);
                        }
                        String[] from = {"name"};
                        int[] to = {R.id.tv_provider_name};
                        final CursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.google_places_list, cursor, from, to,CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY);

                        search.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);

                        search.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                              //  search.setQuery(selectedItem,true);



                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

                                String selectedItem = (String)cursorAdapter.getItem(position);
                                search.setQuery(""+selectedItem,true);


                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: `cursorAdapter.getItem(position);` <-- see what it returns there. there is the mistake. maybe you have to get a `MatrixCursor` and then handle it accordingly?

Comment: Is there any alternative to get selected item from auto suggestions ?

Comment: i'm not so familiar with this, cant help you further.